How to subscribe to services in an angular component?
I have a debate about how to subscribe to services in Angular components.
I got the following ideas:
1) Subscribe in constructor
This solution seems to be more performant as constructor runs a bit sooner than the onInit lifecycle method. Still in construction time the object is not yet stable.
export class App implements OnInit {

    lessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;

    constructor(private lessonsService: LessonsService) {
        this.lessons$ = this.lessonsService.loadLessons().subscribe(
            () => console.log('lessons loaded'),
            console.error
        )
    }
}

2) Subscribe in onInit
This solution seems to be stable by any means, but it is less performant.
export class App implements OnInit {

    lessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;

    constructor(private lessonsService: LessonsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.lessons$ = this.lessonsService.loadLessons().subscribe(
            () => console.log('lessons loaded'),
            console.error
        )
    }
}

I found the following too:

It's good practice to use ngOnInit to subscribe because @Input bindings are not initialized till this lifecycle hook, so they're not ready in the constructor, and often observables can depend upon these values.

And I got a suggestion that subscriptions that do not depend on @Input should be made in constructor for performance considerations.
The following seems way too ugly and inconsistent:
export class App implements OnInit {

    lesson$: Observable<Lesson>;
    lessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;
    @Inpout() id: string;

    constructor(private lessonsService: LessonsService) {
        this.lessons$ = this.lessonsService.loadLessons().subscribe(
            () => console.log('lessons loaded'),
            console.error
        )
    }

    ngOnInit(private lessonsService: LessonsService) {
        this.lesson$ = this.lessonsService.loadLessonById(this.id).subscribe(
            () => console.log('lesson loaded'),
            console.error
        )
    }
}

Could you please help me the right solution.
I searched for references and I only found articles about suggesting the onInit subscription, however I did not found any that compared the two ways.

Can you expand on the performance issue with ngOnInit?

Obviously the constructor is called earlier than ngOnInit. I have not done performance measurements yet. (I do not expect much difference.)
I'm really interested in others experience and ideas on if it is  a valid problem or not.

I very much doubt your assertion that ngOnInit is less performant. The constructor is run first, yes, that doesn't make it better. I bet you a shiny penny your app won't be better off for stuffing everything in the constructor.
You might also run into problems with inheritance and undesirable subscriptions created by the super class if you put them all in the constructor.

In 99.9999% cases it doesnt matter where you write it (if your service subscription doesnt depend on Input for sure). Because both constructor and ngOnInit are executed synchronously one after other (might be some other lifecycle hooks to be run in between). So if your service has some synchronous heavy computations then your rendering will be finished at the same time whether you call service in constructor or not since DOM updates will be applied after all of those are executed.
The only thing I can see might have the difference is that e.g. if you have ngOnChanges with heavy computations (first ngOnChanges is executed after constructor but before ngOnInit) then if you would call your service that makes http call in constructor depending on how different browser handles http calls it might start doing the request to server right away asynchronously while your heavy ngOnChanges runs and then when ngOnInit starts your request might have done half of its way, so you may see the difference.
But it should be the case if you have some heavy computational synchronous stuff between constructor/ngOnInit, otherwise in common cases there is execution time difference in split milliseconds that for sure noone's going to feel. But such computations that impact user experience usually are moved to WebWorkers or something that runs in separate thread not to block the page.
So these micro-optimisations do not really matter except for discussing with your co-worker.
As for me I'd just tend to make less code, so if you have already constructor for injections then just use it for your init code not to create one more class method like ngOnInit. If you need your initial values from inputs then you have no options but to use ngOnOnit. Just keep it simple, you will never notice the difference
